# Get the routed Controller in a Zend_Controller_Plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have to detect which Controller is routed *before* the view script is called (so postDispatch() isn't appropriate).

```
class PerchProvider extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    //if (--CONTROLLERNAME-- != "Error") {

    include APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/perch/runtime.php';

    // }
}
}
```

How can I access the name of the Controller?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register an action helper with a higher priority than the view renderer.

1. In your Bootstrap.php:

   ```
   class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
   {
       protected function _initPerch()
       {
           require APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/helpers/Perch.php';
           Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStack()->offsetSet(2,
                   new Application_Controller_Helper_Perch());
       }
   }
   ```
2. In application/controllers/helpers/Perch.php:

   ```
   <?php

   class Application_Controller_Helper_Perch 
           extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
   {
       public function postDispatch()
       {
           $request = $this->getActionController()->getRequest();
           $controller = $request->getControllerName();
           if ($controller != 'error') {
               include APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/perch/runtime.php';
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting you are integrating perch with Zend !!

According to docs getControllerName is a method on Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract

Comment: Thanks but I guess that won't fix it. The request var contains only the params

Comment: Oh but I guess I'm getting it wrong. ErrorController is only called after the missing Action was routed. Am I right? :/